# Mouse wheel scroll does not always work in Materialize dropdown when using Chrome materialize v1.0.0

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scroll, materialize

After upgrading from v0.100.2 to v1.0.0, the mouse scroll only work intermittently in Chrome. Other browsers work fine.

Specifically, if you mouse wheel scroll with the mouse cursor on the top-left area of the dropdown, it will work. But if you mouse wheel scroll with the cursor elsewhere, it will not work.

[image: demo]
Another observation is if you click one dropdown before clicking and mouse wheel scrolling another dropdown, it will work, so presumably it has something to do with the dropdown close event.

This is the html structure:

```
    <div id="filters" class="modal" style="overflow-y: visible;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Filters</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">

                    <select data-group="List">
                        <option selected="selected" value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="9">2</option>
                        <option value="13">3</option>
                        <option value="12">4</option>
                        <option value="8">5</option>
                        <option value="11">6</option>
                        <option value="19">7</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="List">Label</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <select data-group="ListAgain">
                        <option selected="selected" value="0">one</option>
                        <option value="26">two</option>
                        <option value="25">three</option>
                        <option value="24">four</option>
                        <option value="29">five</option>
                        <option value="23">six</option>
                        <option value="27">seven</option>
                        <option value="30">eight</option>
                        <option value="22">nine</option>
                        <option value="28">ten</option>
                        <option value="21">eleven</option>
                        <option value="31">twelve</option>
                        <option value="0">---</option>
                        <option value="10015">13</option>
                        <option value="10019">14</option>
                        <option value="10021">15</option>
                        <option value="10012">16</option>
                        <option value="10018">17</option>
                        <option value="10011">18</option>
                        <option value="10016">19</option>
                        <option value="10014">20</option>
                        <option value="10020">21</option>
                        <option value="10013">22</option>
                        <option value="10017">23</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="ListAgain">Label Again</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col right">
    <div class="right">
        <a id="show-filters" href="#filters" class="btn-floating modal-trigger" title="Filters">
            <i class="material-icons">filter_list</i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/frostless/pen/bQPLqK (not always work v1.0.0)
https://codepen.io/frostless/pen/aKQEXO (always work v0.100.2)

Answer (score 3):

The issue reported in https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2592

The solution which I found is adding `backface-visibility:hidden` for `.dropdown-content` class. It looks like some browsers can't handle transformations and scrollbars properly.

Answer (score 1):

Found a temporary solution:
It seems like if a select element with class "browser-default" is in the document when the init method is called, the bug would be gone.
So we can append a out-of-document-flow, hidden select element to the body like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').append('<select class="browser-default" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden"></select>'); //this is the hack
    M.AutoInit();
})
```

I know this is not a ultimate solution, but it seems to temporarily fix the bug.
A better solution would need to be done at the low-level of Materialize source code.